# Subfig subfloats don't align horizontally

Tags: subfloats, subfig

for some reason I can't get these two tikzpictures to align next to each other using subfig. They always end up below each other. The width of the tikzpictures doesn't seem to be the issue.

If anyone could help, that would be great!

```
\begin{figure}

    \centering

    \subfloat[i10c01t051a060b050n25m15]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize,draw=none},
        xlabel=eye-sight,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}]

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t051a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {data/Ri10c01t051a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (R)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=diamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retb,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t051a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention believers (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=halfdiamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retd,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t051a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention disbelievers (T)}

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \quad

    \subfloat[i10c01t060a060b050n25m15]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize,draw=none},
        xlabel=eye-sight,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}]

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t060a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {data/Ri10c01t060a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (R)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=diamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retb,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t060a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention believers (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=halfdiamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retd,col sep=comma] {data/Ti10c01t060a060b050n25m15.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention disbelievers (T)}

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code a compilable document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works without empty lines around \quad:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
eye-sight,v-score, retb, retd
1, 2, 3, 5
3, 4, 5, 6
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[i10c01t051a060b050n25m15]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize,draw=none},
        xlabel=eye-sight,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}]

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (R)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=diamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retb,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention believers (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=halfdiamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retd,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention disbelievers (T)}

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[i10c01t060a060b050n25m15]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        legend style={font=\footnotesize,draw=none},
        xlabel=eye-sight,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}]

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] table[x=eye-sight,y=v-score,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{v-score (R)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=diamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retb,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention believers (T)}

        \addplot[smooth,mark=halfdiamond*,blue,dashed] table[x=eye-sight,y=retd,col sep=comma] {test.csv}; 
        \addlegendentry{retention disbelievers (T)}

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't think of that at all! Have a nice day.